# Azure IoT Edge - mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK

Tags: python, azure

I'm facing the following error after scaling the number of connected devices in an Azure IoT Hub - when there was only 1 device connected the issue never came up in 1 month, after installing 3 more it happens randomly approx. once per day in any of the devices (the number of messages sent keeps below the plan limit either way):

```
Error: Time:Thu Mar 28 23:20:30 2019 File:/ioth/azure-iot-sdk-python/azure-iot-sdk-python/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:InitializeConnection Line:2229 mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK
```

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880311/iothub-client-src-iothubtransport-mqtt-common-c-funcinitializeconnection-line2) related topic but my code is running every 1-2 seconds in every device, while the code in `iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c` ([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/ea8d7c29ae313754a2f0972494756b97cc6921d7/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c)) has it defined as 30s the connection timeout:

```
#define DEFAULT_CONNACK_TIMEOUT  30 // 30 seconds
```

Therefore, not sure if this 30s limit is set according to other limitations or this issue could just be solved by increasing the limit and recompiling, any ideas or other possible reasons/solutions? I assume this limit change is just a sort of patch...